# Warning message when using server action in Next.js 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting this warning message in my server-side console when using server actions:

```
Warning: Cannot specify a encType or method for a form that specifies a function as the action. React provides those automatically. They will get overridden.
```

But I am not sure what it means and why it's appearing.

Here's my code:

```
import { makeAction } from "./action";

export default function About() {
  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto mt-10">
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold">Test me</h1>
      <form
        method="post"
        action={makeAction}
        className="space-y-2"        
      >
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Firstname"
          className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs block"
          name="firstName"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="last name"
          className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs block"
          name="lastName"
        />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary block">
          Submit me
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's my `action.ts` file:

```
"use server";
export async function makeAction() {
  console.log(" you made an action ");
}
```

Comment: What is unclear from the error?! You've specified `envType="multipart/form-datas"` (note: **not** an actual [`enctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype)) and a method `method="post"` for a form that specifies a function as the action `action={makeAction}`. It means exactly what it says and is appearing because that's what you've done.

Comment: I removed the prop encType, it's not the cause of the error, actually I added it by mistake

Comment: ... _"or method"_. Cannot recommend enough reading the information you're given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning merely tells you that your

```
encType="multipart/form-datas"
```

will be ignored, because in your scenario, React determines the `encType` automatically, hence your line above will be ignored. The reason given for this is that your action is a function:

```
action={makeAction}
```

and:

```
"use server";
export async function makeAction() {
  console.log(" you made an action ");
}
```

Try removing your `encType` specification and your warning will likely disappear.

You will also need to remove the `method` item to make the warning disappear, as per the warning message.

Comment: I removed it and It didn't disappear

Comment: And I will also update my question to remove it

Comment: I removed the prop `method` and the warning message went away. but I'm not sure why, isn't what we're doing a POST request?

Comment: @Normal actually, you needed to remove both. My answer initially mentioned only one of those, but I edited it to adjust it. Basically if you have a function as an action, then React will specify what the method and the encType will be, so any specification for those in this scenario will have no effect on the program, as React overrides them. This is what the warning informed you about. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `encType` and `method` works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).